# How to provide that a variable of a class declared later should be visible in the previous one?

Tags: c++, circular-dependency, forward-declaration, incomplete-type

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A;
class B;

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {}
    double a;
    vector<B*> vb;
    vector<double> wa;
    void getwa() {for (int i = 0; i < vb.size(); i++) wa.push_back(vb[i]->b);};
};
class B
{
public:
    B() 
    {}
    double b;
    vector<A*> va;
    vector<double> wb;
    void getwb() {for (int i = 0; i < va.size(); i++) wb.push_back(va[i]->a);};
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

which I cannot compile because of using `vb[i]->b`. How to solve that the class `A` should be able to see the variable `b` from the class `B`?

Answer (score 4):

You could separate the class declaration and definition to solve such [circular dependency issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). (And better to put them into separate header fiels and implementation files.) e.g.

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {}
    double a;
    vector<B*> vb;
    vector<double> wa;
    void getwa();
};

class B
{
public:
    B() 
    {}
    double b;
    vector<A*> va;
    vector<double> wb;
    void getwb();
};

void A::getwa() {for (int i = 0; i < vb.size(); i++) wa.push_back(vb[i]->b);}
void B::getwb() {for (int i = 0; i < va.size(); i++) wb.push_back(va[i]->a);}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/FOT24657)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Unfortunately, this code cannot be compiled. Could you please present the whole program text?

Comment: @Roloka I added a live demo for it, please check it.

Comment: Thank you! This is really kind of you! :)